# ASP.net date formatting

Tags: asp.net, date, formatting

I have bound date fields(datetime type column values) to my Grid. In the grid, the column definition is like so
My code is:

```
<asp:Label id="lblFromTimeForTeacher" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FromTime", "{0:hh/mm}")%>' Visible="false" Width="99%" />
```

Right now, the label text is  **08-45**. Could someone please tell how can I get the label text as **08:45**? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom DateTime formatting [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx). In your case just change to `Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("FromTime")).ToString("hh:mm")`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
<asp:Label ID="lblFromTimeForTeacher" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FromTime", "{0:hh:mm}")%>' Visible="false" Width="99%" />
```

if you want in "4:05 PM" format then try the following

```
<asp:Label ID="lblFromTimeForTeacher" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FromTime", "{0:t}")%>' Visible="false" Width="99%" />
```

For more you can review [This Link](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/) hope this will help you.